# commiting setProperty on UserObject in facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I'm developing an android application that uses the Facebook SDK in order to enable Facebook login.
When a user logs in, I create a Request.newMeRequest(...) and override the onCompleted(...).
In the onComplete, I want to check if the user have a property named "Hash". If not, I want to set that property and save it **in my Facebook app**.

```
@Override
public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
    if (user != null) {
        ...   // non relevant code.
        String hash = generateRandomHash();
        user.setProperty("Hash", hash);
    }
}
```

The problem is, that the added property is saved localy in the GraphUser object, and not saved on Facebook for future access.
Is there an easy way to save this data on Facebook for each user that signs into my application using Facebook?

Thank you very much!
Yuval.

Answer (score 0):

AFIK no one will have rights to save data on Facebook except the Facebook itself. You can maintain your own Data Base which can store the Facebook ID and your own property so that you can retrieve the property based on Facebook ID.